# com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-logging-log4j1_2 -- Depends on Vulnerable log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17 version

Tags: log4j, azure-application-insights, telemetry, ilogger

Context:
We use 2.6.3 version of com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-logging-log4j1_2 for instrumenting our Scala code. Unfortunately this depends on 1.2.17 version of log4j:log4j.
1.2.17 version version of log4j:log4j has a Critical security vulnerability (ref: https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2019-17571)
Issue is : "Included in **Log4j 1.2 is a SocketServer class that is vulnerable to deserialization of untrusted data which can be exploited to remotely execute arbitrary code** when combined with a deserialization gadget when listening to untrusted network traffic for log data. This affects Log4j versions up to 1.2 up to 1.2.17"

Resolution is to migrate to **org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core**
Question:
1.) Does Application insight jar use SocketServer class?
2.) Is this a known Vulnerability?
3.) What are the options for us to get a new version of com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-logging-log4j1_2 that uses latest version of org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core

Please any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The [`SocketServer`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SocketServer.html) class is a TCP server, that you can run in a separate JVM in order to **receive** messages from a [`SocketAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SocketAppender.html) in your application. It is **not used** by any other class in the Log4j library.

The [`applicationinsights-logging-log4j1_2`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/applicationinsights-logging-log4j1_2/2.6.3) on the other hand is a very small JAR (2 classes), which provides an `ApplicationInsightsAppender` to allow Log4j 1.2 to **send** logs to Application Insights.

You can **safely** use this and all standard appenders (including `SocketAppender`) without incurring in the problem described in CVE-2019-17571.

#### Migration to Log4j 2.x

Migration to Log4j 2.x is obviously recommended, but for an entirely different reason: it is supported and offers many new features.

The artifact [`applicationinsights-logging-log4j2`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/applicationinsights-logging-log4j2/2.6.3) contains a version of the `ApplicationInsightsAppender`, which can be used with Log4j 2.x.

Comment: Interestingly, CVE-2019-17571 (Log4j 1.2) has a NIST score of 9.8 whereas the more recent CVE-2021-44228 on Log4j 2.x scores 10 (not sure about CVE-2021-45046 yet). Looking into it, the Log4j 1.2 vulnerability looks quite mild (**assuming `SockerServer` is not used**) compared to the recent Log4j vulnerabilities.